# Nested SELECT, or am I over-complicating?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**table1**

```
id
name
number
status
```

**table2**

```
id
table1_id
transaction_no
transaction_date
```

I want to return a list of table1.name, table1.num, table2.transaction_no where the table1.status = "Active" and the lastest table2.transaction_date is older than 4 months.

I keep trying something like this but the syntax fails in various places.

```
SELECT tab1.name, tab1.num, tab2.transaction_no
FROM table1 AS tab1
INNER JOIN table2 AS tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.table1_id
WHERE tab1.status = "Active"
AND 
(SELECT MAX(tab2.transaction_date) FROM tab2 
 GROUP BY tab1.name) <= (date 4 months ago)
```

I know this is not right but my brain is struggling to wrap around the idea, or I making it more complicated that it is. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you to whoever helped with the format!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `GROUP BY tab1.name` doesn't make sense in your subquery. `tab1` isn't in context in your subquery (nor is`tab2` for that matter). Instead though you could do a correlated subquery:

```
AND (SELECT MAX(t2.transaction_date) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.table1_id = tab1.id) <= (date 4 months ago)
```

Now that subquery can stand on it's own, and it is properly correlated to the main query by way of it's WHERE clause.

If you only want the latest t2 record (and it has to be more than 4 months ago) then a subquery in your FROM clause would work:

```
SELECT tab1.name, tab1.num, tab2.transaction_no
FROM table1 AS tab1
   INNER JOIN (
    SELECT transaction_no, table1_id 
    FROM table2 t2 
    WHERE transaction_date = (SELECT max(transaction_date) FROM table2 WHERE table1_id = t2.table1_id)
   ) AS tab2 
    ON tab1.id = tab2.table1_id
WHERE tab1.status = "Active";
```

Here we are still using a correlated subquery to grab the record from table2 that has the greatest transaction_date for each table1_id. Then we are joining that one record per table1_id back to table1.id.

Comment: That is a step in the right direction as soon as it lets me I will mark it correct. I forgot to mention I only want the latest transaction from table2.